# Recover Socket after restoring a snapshot

Tags: c, sockets, virtualbox

I have to following problem. Maybe someone could help me with that.

What I want do achieve is that a service inside a virtual machine (using
virtualbox/WinXP) should send data to the host via socket (client)(1). The host
(socketserver) then takes a snapshot of the current system(2), sends an ack(3) into
the vm (again via socket), that every action was taken and that the service
can continue(4).

```
Service                                               Host
=========                                               =======

Service sends specific data (1)

        ---------------------------------------->       
                                                        Invoke Snapshot (2)
| On restore socket gets destroyed  (X) |
| No ACK can be accepted -- Endless Loop|               Send ACK (3)

        <----------------------------------------

Accept ACK and continue (4)
```

The Problem occurs, when I restore the vm to a state, which was taken earlier.
The software waits for the ack to continue. The vm takes some time to restore
its network (3-5 seconds until "your network cable is now plugged in..." in
the tray) and this crashes the sockets (X).

I don't have a workaround for that. The Service is written in C. Host is a
python script. Sleep is the worst solution in my opinion. Due to high load,
the time until something happens is not predictable.

I cannot come up with a great idea on how to solve that problem. Would be
great if you could help me.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

@alk: I made the assumption, because the client is not connected to server anymore (different states due to restore, and losing the connection for a while I guess)

Here is the C Code from the Service. I hooked certain syscalls, and the code gets executed when a syscall is called

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET s;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char buffer[1024];
char ack[1024];
int recv_size;

int mpex_send(const char *str, ...)
{
    // Build String
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, str);
    vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), str, va);
    va_end(va);

    // Init
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.56.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 42000 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");
     //Send some data
    if( send(s , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Data Send\n");

    //Receive a reply from the server
    while(1)
    {
        if((recv_size = recv(s , ack , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            puts("recv failed");
        }

        puts("Reply received\n");
        ack[recv_size] = '\0';
        puts(ack);
        // Important, put \n after ack
        if (strcmp("ack\n", ack) == 0)
        {
            puts("Got it");
            break;
        }
    }
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the service issue a blocking `recv` which would cause it to wait for the ACK from the Host?

Comment: How do you exactly come to this assumption "*... and this crashes the sockets (X).*" and exactly do you ant to express, please?

Comment: However if you can provide the source describing the part of the process that hangs, we can provide more then wild guesses but (hopefully) answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. Maybe someday will encounter the same, so hopefully this helps.

After the first message from the C code is sent, it will go into a loop state where it tries to create and open a socket (see source above). If they succeed they break; the loop. After that I loop a socket.recv to get the ack from the host.

In this state the host got the message and falls into an ack flooding state, where it sends an ack to all connected clients. So the message is sent to the new connections as well as to the broken ones.

After the C code received the ack, it sends an ack_ack to the host to stop flooding.

This page was very helpful for the python server part. 
http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/

Hope this helps